# Trouble commiting to subversion server using apache

Tags: linux, apache, svn

My Archlinux server uses Apache 2.0 and subversion to give access over internet to my svn server. However after setting it up I can't even commit locally.

My httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80

LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so

User http
Group http

DocumentRoot "/srv/http"

<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /home/sendo/svn/repository
</Location>
```

I used:

```
svnadmin create /home/sendo/svn/repository/projectx
```

then:

```
chown -R http.http /home/svn/repository/projectx
```

after this I try to import files from the svn server with:

```
svn import -m "Initial import" http://mydomain.topdomain/svn/projectx/
```

and I get

svn: E000013: Unable to connect to repository at url http://mydomain.topdomain/svn/projectx/

svn: E000013: Could not open the requested SVM filesystem

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
SVNPath /home/sendo/svn/repository
```

means:

- you have one repo,
- this repo must be created in /home/sendo/svn/repository, not one level below

Comment: so you mean I should use 
    svnadmin create /home/sendo/svn/projectx

Comment: @user1106784 No, /home/sendo/svn/repository. If you want to use more than one repository under common root, you have to use  'SVNParentPath /home/sendo/svn/repository
SVNListParentPath on`

Comment: I see, even if I change my location to SVNParentPath to /home/sendo/svn/repository
and add the SVNListParentPath on
I get the same two errors

Comment: 1. SVNBook tells about **only two** DAV-modules, without dav_fs_module  2. Before import *to* repository (from current path, if path omitted) check `svn co http://mydomain.topdomain/svn/projectx/` in some location 3. Enable logging for SVN and check logs

Comment: yea tried svn co http://mydomain.topdomain/svn/projectx/ with no success, the svn co svn://mydomain.topdomain/projectx did work though

Comment: svn: protocol isn't Apache part. Which errors in log forco http:// you get? Did you restart Apache after editing config?

Comment: yea did restart apache, I get "OPTIONS /projectx HTTP/1.1" 200 -
in access_log

Comment: 200 code isn't error. It's "OK" code. Add files to WC now, try to commit to repo

Comment: I have no idea what to do any more to be honest.
I tried svn import and co with different access methods
svn:// and http:// and with 
mydomain.topdomain/svn/ and
mydomain.topdomain/svn/projectx
and none of them work, I get obscure info and I have no idea any longer what is the right thing to do.